# Prove that $Au\cdot v = u\cdot A^Tv$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let A be an $n$ x $n$ matrix and let $u$,$v$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R^n}$. Prove that $$Au\cdot v = u\cdot A^Tv$$

I tried using the fact that $A^Tu=A\cdot u$. However, I cannot seem to get to this result. Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: How do you define the inner product exactly?

Comment: If you define $\langle x , y \rangle = x^T y$, then $\langle Ax , y \rangle = (Ax)^T y = x^T A^T y = x^T (A^Ty) = \langle x , A^Ty \rangle$. The key fact here is that $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you! That's what I needed. I have one question though, why is this true $x^TA^Ty=x^T(A^Ty)$ ?

Comment: @mause Multiplication of matrices is associative.

Comment: To elaborate on @Silencer's comment: For any appropriately sized matrices $A,B,C$, we have $(AB)C = A(BC)$. So we can write $ABC$ without any ambiguity.

Comment: Glad to help. Its a community process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that $x\cdot y:=y^Tx$, for any $x,y\in \Bbb R^n$, you'll have:

$Au\cdot v=(Au\cdot v)^T=v^TAu=(v^TA)u=\cdots$

The first equality is a consequence of the fact that $Au\cdot v$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix.

Comment: $x\cdot y$ is not equal to $y^Tx$, is it?

Comment: It is, the transpose of a real number is the same number. I have more usually seen  $x \cdot y = x^T y$.

Comment: @mause Aren't you working with the standard dot product in R^n?

Comment: Yes I am. But as copper.hat mentioned, I am more familiar with the identity $x\cdot y$ = $x^Ty$ so this confused me.

Comment: @mause Good, that will force you to think about your definition (which is only slightlty different from the one I used).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I see now why your definition is indeed the same as I am used too. Thanks again :)

Comment: Comment downvoter?