# Proof of inner product property: $\langle Ax,x \rangle = \langle x,A^Tx \rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

$A$ is a matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I want to prove that: $$\langle Ax, x \rangle = \langle x , A^T x \rangle $$

Having $A^T$ as the transpose of the matrix $A$.

---

*Just realized I use this property so much, yet I don't known how to prove it.*

Comment: Since $Ax \in \mathbb{R}^m$, that statement only really makes sense if $m=n$.  What's true more generally: if $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$, then $\langle Ax, y \rangle = \langle x, A^T y \rangle$.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2411517/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/353147/42969

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that by definition

$$\langle Ax, x \rangle = (x^TA^T)x=x^T(A^Tx)=\langle x , A^T x \rangle$$

with $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, otherwise

$$\langle Ax, y \rangle = (x^TA^T)y=x^T(A^Ty)=\langle x , A^T y \rangle$$

with $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: So the definition of inner product is $\langle x,y \rangle = x^T y$?

Comment: @Figurinha Yes in this case we are referring to that definition.